# Custom Migration - Encrypted Core Data - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sqlcipher, encrypted-core-data-sql

Does ***EncryptedCoreData*** support changing the **Entity Attribute Type** and thus can it successfully do custom migrations in iOS?

I have installed pod EncryptedCoreData for a swift iOS project and I am able to encrypt the sqldatabase file. I can also do light weight migrations such as adding an attribute to the existing Entity and Adding an Entity etc. But I am not able to change the attribute type of an Entity.

Comment: Are you having any specific problems?

Comment: Yes, I have installed pod EncryptedCoreData for a swift iOS project and I am able to encrypt the sqldatabase file. I can also do light weight migrations such as adding an attribute to the existing Entity and Adding an Entity etc. But I am not able to change the attribute type of an Entity .

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Something like "The source and target attribute type is not same". But without ECD the same project successfully do the migration of Attribute type

Comment: Maybe raise it as an issue over at the GitHub repo for that project.